# printf \'<a>\' gives error - cannot find the file specified

Tags: linux, bash, printf

When I run `printf '<a>'` I get what I expect.

When I run `printf \'<a>\'` I get ... cannot find the file specified.

When I am executing printf from NodeJS v6.11.3 it is forcing the latter. Anyone know why and how I might get past this?

I am running git bash on Windows.

Comment: I found something vaguely related curiosity in a production makefile last week.  The command lines echoed by `make` said: `<file1.in> file1.out sed -e 's/something/other thing/'`.  It works; it edits `file1.in` and sends the output to `file1.out` even though they both appear before the `sed` command.  I/O redirection is nothing if not flexible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you make the quotes not-special (by escaping them) then `<` becomes a redirect and tries to redirect stdin from a file named `a`.  You just need to find the right quoting/escaping to make sure the `printf` doesn't have too many escapes.

If you are trying to print the single quotes themselves try

```
 printf "'<a>'"
```

Comment: thanks in NodeJS I had to wrap the string in double quotes not single quotes to prevent this